# How to get value of R, G, and B from RGB string in dart?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I've tried the following code in dart, but unable to get solution.

```dart
RegExp rgb = RegExp(r"^rgb\(([0-9]+),\s*([0-9]+),\s*([0-9]+)\)$");
final match = rgb.allMatches("rgb(127, 127, 126)");
```

I can easily do it in javascript with the above regular expression using `rgb.exec(String)` method which returns array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the capture groups using the `groups` method:

```
RegExp rgb = RegExp(r"^rgb\(([0-9]+),\s*([0-9]+),\s*([0-9]+)\)$");
final matches = rgb.allMatches("rgb(127, 127, 126)");
for (final match in matches) {
    final colors = match.groups([1, 2, 3]);
    print('red: ${colors[0]}, green: ${colors[1]}, blue: ${colors[2]}');
}
```